# Why is my mongodb connection not working , even though everything is installed? Homebrew, macos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

I've installed mongodb using homebrew and its running as a service,

```
[~]$ brew services list                     
Name              Status  User      File
mongodb-community started <User> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
postgresql        started <User> ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

I can connect to the mongo shell and connect via compass, however when I connect via an application. using the local connection string I get the following,

```
error - MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
```

I've ran mongod for testing and I got the following,

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.991+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.995+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.995+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.995+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.996+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6303,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Bens-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.extfeatures"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.3","gitVersion":"657fea5a61a74d7a79df7aff8e4bcf0bc742b748","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.1.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:56.997+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.001+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.002+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-26T13:39:57.003+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}
```

from what I can tell everything mongodb wise is all setup so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.

I'm using macos monterey and vscode.

Comment: `"SocketException","errmsg":"Address already in use"` - Which port did you configure? Did you start the service twice?

Comment: I only have one service listed so I assume it's only been ran once, is there a way to check @WernfriedDomscheit?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've ran `sudo chown -R `id -un` /opt/homebrew/var/mongodb` and I have restarted mongodb-community. I can confirm a connection is running by using `ps aux | grep -v grep | grep mongod` but I'm still getting `MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017`

Comment: How did you start the service?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I started it using `brew services start mongodb-community`, running `brew services list` - I can see that it's started `mongodb-community started <user>` so honestly I'm at a loss

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've checked the firewall and I'm allowing incoming connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WernfriedDomscheit, got it working.

Had to change the config `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf` net block too.

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```